# How to return rows where the ID is in all of the list?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to return all employeeID's that have sold a list of productID's.

So I have a transactions table that has:

transactions
-id
-employeeID
-productID

So I want to return all employeeID's that have sold products 1023, 2012, 3941 and 2012.

```
select productID
from transactions
where productID IN (1023, 2012, 3941, 2012)
```

The above query is wrong because it will return rows if a employee sold just 1 from the list, I want to only return employees that have sold ALL those products.

Comment: Does my answer works for you?

Comment: I will test it out today and get back to you thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use group by and having clause, which will check that the total amount of products sold by an employee is 4(after filtering only the products ID needed of course)

```
SELECT employeeID
FROM transactions
WHERE productID IN (1023, 3941, 2012)
GROUP BY employeeID
HAVING COUNT(distinct productID) = 3
```

I think you got some kind of mistake there, 2012 twice? anyway i removed one of it.. if you meant another one instead of 2012, add it in the IN statement and change the number to 4

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. Sadly, it won't work as posted because it suffers the same logical issue as the OP. They have 2012 in the list twice. Regardless this gets a vote from me because this is the correct technique.

Comment: @SeanLange 1) how do you know? and 2) i used count distinct, so it will ignore the second one.. Who downvoted me?

Comment: Yes it will ignore the second one which means the count would be 3, not 4. :D

Comment: Oh lol, didn't look at the content of it since it doesn't make any sense.. that I'll change it to 3 @SeanLange

Comment: Many downvoters never bother to provide a reason. Such is the nature of SO. You are back to 0 with my vote. :D